# "bash" not found when running xargs in kubernetes

Tags: linux, awk, kubectl, xargs

I am trying to use/understand `xargs` for printing various details for some pods I have running in kubernetes across different namespaces. E.g. this command gives:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep Error | awk '{print $2 " -n=" $1}'
my-pod-kf8xch6y-qc6ms-k6ww2 -n=my-ns
my-pod-kf8xlg64-g0ss7-mdv1x -n=my-ns
my-pod-kldslg64-polf7-msdw3 -n=another-ns
```

which is correct/expected.

When I add `xargs` to the above command I get:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep Error | awk '{print $2 " -n=" $1}' | xargs kubectl $1 get pod $0 -oyaml | grep phase
Error from server (NotFound): pods "bash" not found
phase: Failed
phase: Failed
```

Which is actually the expected output but I don't understand

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "bash" not found
```

why is `bash` passed to `xargs`?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the argument `$0` is assigned the first part of the full command from the shell you are using. If you'd be using `zsh` it would say that instead of `bash`. Try on the console `echo $0` without anything else to see what I mean. Bash puts `bash` into `$0`.

Comment: you are right printing $0 shows that the first value is `bash`. But how do I pass the two outputs from awk into xargs as separate arguments?

Comment: What commands do you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

We suggest to avoid `xargs` complications and combine maximum into single `awk` script.

```
kubectl get pods -A | awk '/Error/{system("kubectl get pod "$2" -n="$1" -oyaml")}'|grep phase
```

Or get even more detailed results:

```
kubectl get pods -A | awk '/Error/{system("kubectl get pod "$2" -n="$1" -oyaml")}'|grep -E  "(^  name|^  phase)
```